# Missing argument In my controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hey I am trying to update user profile by sending an id to controller. Every time I submit my form it gives me error missing argument. I have defined route and included id parameter in my controller function but then tooo I get the error.

Code for my controller is

```
 public function update_avatar(Request $request,$id)
{
    $this->validateInput($request);
    $u = User::findOrFail($id);
    dd($u);
    //Handle the user upload of avatar
    if($request->hasFile('avatar'))
    {
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($avatar)->resize(300,300)->save(public_path('/uploads/'.$filename));

    }
     $user = Auth::user();
        $user->name = $request->name;
        dd($user->name);
        $user->email = $request->email;
        if($request->password == null)
        {
            $user->password = $u->password;
        }
        $user->password = $request->password;
        $user->avatar = $filename;
        $user->role = 'admin';
        $user->save();
    return view('/adminPanel/adminProfile',array('user' => Auth::user()));
}
```

code of my view

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('profile', ['id' => $user->id]) }}" method="post">
```

And my route is

```
  Route::post('/adminPanel/id/adminProfile',
'AdminProfileController@update_avatar')
 ->name('profile')->middleware('admin');;
```

Answer (score 3):

In your route use. You missing parenthesis. When you pass id or any value using route, you have must use parenthesis for this.

```
Route::post('/adminPanel/{id}/adminProfile','AdminProfileController@update_avatar')->name('profile')->middleware('admin');
```